# How to get php variable value dynamically in modal in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I want to get phone number dynamically when users click "View detail" button.
`<?php $owner_mobile = $post->phone_no; ?>`

$owner_mobile get the all post mobile number and display dynamically. When i use as it is in modal then i got the last mobile number those are store in these variable. But i want number get dynamically when click these post "View detail"

```
<div class="row">   
        <?php $owner_mobile = $post->phone_no; ?>       
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><strong><?php echo lang_key('interested');?></strong></button>
</div>
```

How get number dyanamically when user click view detail in modal

Answer (score 1):

Modal ID Should be dynamic. 
Please show your complete code with modal.
You should add some unique values(Id) with data-target

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $id;?>">
```

In the modal section also you should use some dynamic values with id

```
<div id="myModal<?php echo $id;?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```